# How can I format a certain string (date) in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In order to fit my code, I needed to convert today's year to a two digit number (the last two digits).
To test this, I tried:

```vb
Sub test()

Dim y As String

y = Format(Year(Now), "00")

MsgBox (y)
End Sub
```

I was told by a classmate that I could use the "Mid" function, but I'm not very familiar with VBA; any help?

Comment: Using format you use the letter that you want, so `D` for day, `M` for month and `Y` for year. The number of letters you use determines how it comes out. So `YY` will give you `21` whereas `YYYY` will give you `2021`. Another example for a full date: `"DD-MM-YY` will give `24-01-21` whereas `"DD-MMM-YYYY"` will give `24-Jan-2021`. Also instead of `Year(Now)`, either use `Date` or `Now()`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
y = Format(Date, "YY")
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub test()

Dim y As String

y = Right(Year(Now), 2)

MsgBox (y)
End Sub
```